# Response from Mainframes to iseries

Tags: ibm-midrange, mainframe, connect-direct

I have an iseries job that sends files to Mainframes via NDM (Connect Direct).  CDSND and CDRUNJOB commands for this purpose.

The issues is although my Copy and Run tasks complete successfully, there is some failure in the Mainframes side which I am not able to capture.

Mainframe team has come back with a reason that the transmission job does not get an initiator immediately due to a loaded system.

Is there any way I could get a response from Mainframes to iseries after a job got into the initiator queue and got a slot and executed successfully.

Comment: You are using both CDSND and CDRUNJOB? Isn't CDSND going to tell you whether a file transfer worked? If you use CDRUNJOB, you'd need to communicate the result of the step back to yourself. There are... several... ways to do that. The best way, is the way your Production Control department want to do it.

Comment: Thanks Bill. Is it the notify parameter on  CDRUNJOB command that will update the status of the mainframes job

Comment: I'm not sure than you can get the NOTIFY to route to your i/Series. It can be sent to a remote z/OS or VM userid. If your i/Series is defined as a "node", perhaps, but your z/OS technical staff would know. You could use NDM to send a response back (I assume it is also running on z/OS) or FTP, or anything you have for messaging between the two systems (avoid email as there is nothing to say the email will arrive in a timely manner). However, you really need to get the z/OS technical people to tell you how they want it done. Fishing the web for solutions will likely just get them bounced.

Comment: Thank you for the information, Bill. I would not have reached the web if I had got some help from my z/os person :)

Comment: Sometimes you get a viscous circle. Spelled as intended. The most reasonable way to do it depends on how the z/OS and i/Series are set up, and what specific software, including vendor software, they have installed. You could get 20 solutions suggested to you, and have all 21 of them rejected for some reason or another. If your z/OS technicians are not cooperating, your have to set everything out for your boss, and let your boss deal with their boss. You can indicate that too them first "I really need a solution on this, so I have to escalate it soon" and give them another go, or not..

Comment: Oh. And if you don't include what you've tried in your question, expect to get busted on it. If you come back "yeah, I tried that before, dummo", expect a message like this :-) OK, I know you didn't quite do that. One problem is your question is not a good fit here, which is a Q&A site, whereas an i/Series or Mainframe Forum may be better, but still have the same problem (they don't work at your site).